# Will data be lost

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list

If I change a multi line text column from allowing plain text to allowing rich text will the existing data be lost? I have been asked to modify an existing multi line text column to allow the insertion of hyperlinks.

Comment: Can you create a custom list to test it out yourself? Create a list, add a multiline text field that allows only plain text, add a list item and put some dummy data in there, then change the field and see what happens... Then when you're done you can just delete the list.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, existing data will not be lost when we change a **Multiple lines of text** column from Plain text to Enhanced rich text